# How Can I get rid of the gap between 2 divs in a Bootstrap grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to build a  grid system in Bootstrap that allows me to stack 3 cols one besides the other in MD size and another col that goes full with underneath them. 
That goes fine, but when I arrive to LG size I need 2 of the columns go to the right and the first one stays at size 9. Please have a look, http://codepen.io/renzosalvador/pen/doyEwd

```
<div class="container">
```

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-9 col-lg-9 " style="background:tomato; ">
  DESCRIPTION
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:cyan; height:250px;">
  PIC
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background:green; height:250px;">
  PRICE
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9" style="background:blue; overflow:hidden; top:10%;">
  TABLE BOX INFO
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the `pull-right` class on the PRICE column..

http://www.codeply.com/go/EIc7CEtkfz

Another way would be to change the structure, and use 2 columns with nested inner columns..

http://www.codeply.com/go/AOGErMq6CM

Comment: Hi there, As you can see the  solution isn´t yet solving the gap between  Description and  Table box info...   http://codepen.io/renzosalvador/pen/doyEwd

Comment: The codepen is different than the examples in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Default bootstrap has a column total size of '12'. But your col-lg is much larger (and therefore the columns don't do what you expect to see).

Comment: The OP means the gap created by column height